# DotNetNuke: Delete unused Extensions after upgrade

Tags: c#, vb.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

I have upgraded a site from dnn 4.8 to 9.1.1.

During this upgrade various pre-installed Extensions become obsolete, I check these obsolescence with a clean dotnetnuke 9.1.1 installation.

I have some issues and I think that they are generated from conflicted obsolete extensions.

Some extensions are deletable but someone like this are not:
[image]

As showed up in the image, Messaging extension is an obsolescence from dnn 6.1.5.
The new Messaging Center extension is correctly installed, so I want to delete Messaging.

How can I delete these extensions?

Can I show this button modifying some db table?

Thanks

Comment: Did you update from 4 to 9 without steps in between? If so you can probably expect more issues since the gap between those versions is rather large.

Comment: we have do all suggested updgrade path, with variuos version step

Comment: Thats good. But some modules cannot be deleted since they are part of the DNN core (like the Message Center).

Comment: The issue is that we have both Message Center and Messaging extension... but messaging extension is obsolete (like many other) and we want to remove them